# error cs0246 the type or namespace cannot be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a racing game and am now stuck because of this error and i have no idea how to fix it.[This is the code that i am trying i have also tried to do it on multiple platforms as i thought that could help. I am a beginner to this and need to fix this for a school project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmYMK.png) the problem that i am having is that when i put this code on my car i get multiple errors such as error cs0246 the type or namespace name "wheelcollider" and "transform" cannot be found.

Comment: In order to get help can you put your code here.

Comment: It would be best to edit your code and any errors into the question as text. In programming case is very important. `wheelcollider != WheelCollider` and `transform != Transform`.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used Unity before, but I am pretty sure it's a matter of casing.

C# is case-sensitive for its identifiers, so if you want to use [WheelCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider.html) class, the following won't work:

```
public wheelcollider someName;
public transform someName2;
```

You will need to use this instead:

```
public WheelCollider someName;
public Transform someName;
```

Pay close attention to the casing in the type. Most types in C# are (if not all), by convention, PascalCase.

*(I would leave it as a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough SO reputation, so I will leave it here)*